# Parse.com how to do sorting and query on included ParseObject?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to do sorting and querying on a list from `Parse`:

```
new Parse.Query('StoreCard')
  .include('user') // user is a Pointer to the User class
  .matches('user.name', new RegExp('abc', 'i')
  .ascending('user.name');
```

However I've been trying for so long to make it work when having to query on included `ParseObject`s such as `user` in this case, but without success.

Getting it to work on non-included properties is no problem such as this example:

```
new Parse.Query('StoreCard')
  .include('user') // user is a Pointer to the User class
  .matches('storecardName', new RegExp('abc', 'i')
  .ascending('storecardName');
```

I can't find any examples nor documentation on how to achieve what I need..

Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done without adjustment to the model.  If the data is small-ish, you could do the sort on the client or in a cloud function.  For something time-critical, bigger, that might be paginated, I suggest adding a `userName` property to the `StoreCard`, and setting it in a `beforeSave` trigger on StoreCard.

You may also discover that you need only the userName and a small set of other user fields on that `StoreCard`, in which case you can denormalize all of them and skip the `.include` query, too.